# Conditional regex replace in nodejs

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have an address like this:

```
117042,ABC DEF,HIJ KLMNOP,9,170
```

and want to have

```
117042,ABC DEF,HIJ KLMNOP 9 170
```

I tried it with this replace Regex

```
address = address.replace(/,[\d]/g, " ");
```

but this results in

```
117042,ABC DEF,HIJ KLMNOP  70
```

I do not want to replace the digit but still need to check if the digit comes after the comma to not match the other commas.

I am not very good with regex thats why I am asking for help.

Comment: [`.replace(/,(\d+),(\d+)$/, ' $1 $2')`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ae493y2d/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may only replace commas after numbers if they occur at the end of string:

```js
var s = "117042,ABC DEF,HIJ KLMNOP,9,170";
var res = s.replace(/,(\d+)(?=(?:,\d+)*$)/g, " $1");
console.log(res);
```

The [`,(\d+)(?=(?:,\d+)*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/eelDus/1) regex matches:

- `,` - a comma
- `(\d+)` - (Group 1, referred to via `$1` from the replacement pattern) one or more digits
- `(?=(?:,\d+)*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires 0+ sequences of `,` + one or more digits at the end of the string.